# Laravel | oneToMany with two foreign keys

Tags: laravel, model, foreign-keys, relation, laravel-5.5

I have two tables, `invoice_header` and `invoice_detail`
Both tables have `loc_id` and `invo_no` as reference keys between them.

How can I link them inside the model, can I use array for foreign keys?

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class InvoiceDetail extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'invoice_detail';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['invo_no','loc_id','serial','item_id','qty','rtp','cost',
                           'discount','type'];

    public function item(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\InvoiceHeader', ['loc_id', 'invo_no']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

You will want a details model and and invoice header model and invoice model and inter connect them.follow the article or rename your model to invoice and make to functions

```
//details 
public function invoice(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Invoice::class);

}
//invoice model
public function details(){
   return $this->hasMany(InvoiceDetails::class);

}
public function headers(){
   return $this->hasMany(InvoiceHeaders::class);

}
//headers model
public function invoice(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Invoice::class);

}



//then you can get details and headers through

$invoice = Invoice::find(1);
$details = $invoice->details;
$headers = $invoice->headers;
```

Comment: Can I get header through details $details->header?

Comment: yeah you would do the same thing as what i wrote for invoice model and the article tells you how to specify the fks being used

Comment: `return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`

Comment: I have to have Invoice table as I am getting an error it's not exist.